# How can I fix the lower limit of bar plots

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to fix the limit of the barplot at `y=2 (ylim=2)`

```
testdata <- data.frame(group=c(1,2),
             xbar= c(3.410821 , 4.746693 ),
                 se = c(0.1593839,0.2435023))

xvals = with(testdata,barplot(xbar, names.arg=group, 
                main="",xlab="x",ylab="y",ylim=c(2,max(6))))

   with(testdata,arrows(xvals, xbar, xvals, xbar+se, length=0.3, angle=90, code=2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `xpd` parameter like this:

```
xvals = with(testdata,barplot(xbar, names.arg=group, 
                              main="",xlab="x",ylab="y",ylim=c(2,6),xpd=FALSE))
```

[image]